# how to define a 3-way relationship in ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 3 tables: Users, Organizations, Roles. How can I define the relationship between them using ef core code first?  For example, a user can be a president for multiple organizations.

EDIT: for those it's not obvious enough: I know about O2M and M2M approaches but in this scenario I want to make sure that a particular user and their role only go with a certain organization. So for example, User1 can be a President for Org1, Org2, but a Janitor for Org3 and has no role in Org4.

Comment: I would suggest to read a tutorial about code first approaches implementing a 1 => many relationship like [this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-entity-framework-core-and-code-first-migrations-in-ef-core/)

Comment: please don't downvote if you don't know the answer. Ofcourse I know about O2M and M2M approaches. In this particular scenario I want to be able to say a user is only a president for a certain company.

Comment: I guess you need to be more precise in your problem description. It is just too vague up to now

Comment: Riz, I would suggest read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and ask again. We definitely will help you. But right now your question is too vague and not clear.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how it's too vague. I have described a scenario in detail, and edited my post in case it wasn't clear.

Comment: "I am not sure I understand how it's..." this is exactly how I fell :) but chit chat aside, Do you want to forbid that `User1` can have a rolre in `Org4` ? am I right? this sounds like you would need to do it on the code level when inserting the data. I don't see any abvious reason why he can be president of 2 organizations have a third role in `Org3` but is not allowed in the fourth

Comment: it's not about not allowing or allowing him. It's just that he has no relationship with that particular organization. Think about a real world scenario rather than just purely from db perspective.

Comment: It's really not hard to define rules. If it's so obvious, why not just state them rather than expect others to do the work for you AND play guess 21?

Comment: You can use a fourth table to relate Users, Organizations, Roles (in case Roles are just meant to be a role of a user inside an organization). Make a new model that relate the other three.

Comment: I thought I already did state them. did you read the original post?

Comment: thanks Ammar. I was just thinking the same thing: create a UserRoleOrg class which has User, Org, Role, and then relate that class as m2m to both Orgs and Users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following are the models for User, Organization and Role

```
public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}

public class Organization {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}

public class Role {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

If the case is like this (a user in an organization can have one role at most in that organization), then you can relate all three models by creating a new model that do that for you.

```
public UserOrganizationRole {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties if you want

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Or create 2 models, one to relate Users and Organizations as M2M say UserOrganizations, and the other to relate UserOrganizations and Roles as M2M

```
public UserOrganization {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties if you want

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}

public UserOrganizationRole {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties if you want

    public int UserOrganizationId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public UserOrganization UserOrganization { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```